# Im getting this error after just updating my flutter,Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 64,Could not find a command named "-"

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

I have just updated my flutter and I got this error:

`Could not find a command named "-".`

and Exception:

`Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 64`

I am continuously getting this error. I am not able to run my app. My Whole Error Log is like this:

---

```
*Could not find a command named "-".

Usage: dart <command|dart-file> [arguments]

Global options:
-h, --help                 Print this usage information.
-v, --verbose              Show additional command output.
    --version              Print the Dart SDK version.
    --enable-analytics     Enable analytics.
    --disable-analytics    Disable analytics.
Available commands:
  analyze    Analyze Dart code in a directory.
  compile    Compile Dart to various formats.
  create     Create a new Dart project.
  devtools   Open DevTools (optionally connecting to an existing application).
  doc        Generate HTML API documentation from Dart documentation comments.
  fix        Apply automated fixes to Dart source code.
  format     Idiomatically format Dart source code.
  migrate    Perform null safety migration on a project.
pub        Work with packages.
  run        Run a Dart program.
  test       Run tests for a project.

Run "dart help <command>" for more information about a command.
See https://dart.dev/tools/dart-tool for detailed documentation.
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 64
*
```

**My Code**
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
       
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);


  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
  
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
     
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
       
        child: Column(
     
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ), 
    );
  }
}[![you can see in [https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRW2i.png][1]  that i run this app from vs code run button but it gives the error in debug console ][1]][1]
```

Comment: Could you show us what command did you use to run/build the app?

Comment: i didn't run any command i just run my app in android studio using run button

Comment: Can you share the full output of the console, then? `Could not find a command named "-".` seems like some kind of misconfiguration in your IDE.

Comment: well thanks for trying to help me out but actually that error was because of the wrong path name of my project i.e.  i was using  non alphabet words(like: numbers ) in project path